# How would luck egalitarianism deal with AI and automatisation in production?

Tags: ethics, artificial-intelligence, justice, rawls

Mainstream theories of justice, particularly luck egalitarianism, accept that the "good fortune," the goods that result from endowments, not from choice or effort, be redistributed to aid those victims of bad luck (mostly bad brute luck but also bad option luck). They do not allow the goods resulting from effort and choice by people to be distributed in that way.

a) What about the goods resulting from the production done by a conscious robot? Would it be treated as "good fortune" and thus redistributed? If not, whose holdings would they become? The owner of the robot? The robot itself?

b) What about bad (brute or option) luck by the robot? Would it entitle it to aid?

c) Can these be answered solely within the frameworks of analytical philosophy and theories of justice or do we need the aid of other theories?

Comment: The answer is that we will get to it when we get close to having conscious robots, and if we never do (which is very likely) then the issue will have resolved itself. So there is no point puzzling over it now. Distribution and ownership are social arrangements influenced by balancing many cultural and pragmatic considerations, they can not be decided before something that does not yet exist brings them about.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Question is a bit broad and very opinion based. You'd be interested in the [uncanny valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley), [altruism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism), [empathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy), and [morality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morality). Also see [anthropomorphization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism) and [objectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectification). Human psychology is complex, and it's likely the human reaction will be complex.